# How to hide implementation

Tags: c#, oop

Lets say I have a class library, where any classes that are internal have access to the following interface:

```
interface myInterface
{
    string myProperty { get; set; } // notice setter.
}
```

But if somebody adds this class library to their project they get the following interface:

```
public interface myInterface
{
    string myProperty { get; }
}
```

What is the most efficient and accepted way of doing this? Have one interface implement the other?

Answer (score 2):

Make your public interface have just the getter:

```
public interface myInterface
{
    string myProperty { get; } 
}
```

And then derive another internal-only interface from it that has a setter:

```
internal interface myInternalInterface : myInterface
{
    new string myProperty { get; set; }
}
```

You can them implement the internal interface:

```
class myImplementation : myInternalInterface
{
    public string myProperty{get; set;}
}
```

If you need to call the setter, you can cast your instance to the internal inteface and call it on that. This approach is a bit of a design smell though, so use it sparingly.

Comment: this is pretty cool - except for the fact that there's no real benefit in this inheritance.  Public APIs for the library can only expose `myInterface`, and since the inheritance is done the other way around there's never any guarantee that a `myInterface` is also a `myInternalInterface` - much the same as in my answer.

Comment: You can call the setter on an instance typed as the class `myImplementation` as well internally.

Comment: You don't even need to have the myInternalInterface.  The myInterface defines that you should have a getter.  You can perfectly create a class which implements this interface.  The class has to have a property which has the getter, but it is also perfectly legal to make sure that this property has an (internal) setter as well. (See the deleted answer of squillman as well).

Comment: @AndrasZoltan: I agree that it's pretty horrible, but it does work. I don't think any approach along these lines will work nicely without there being some casting involved (and probably some knowledge that the interface being cast to does actually derive from the original one). I would try to design my classes differently so that I did not need to do this.

Comment: There's another thing - the need for the public and internal interfaces suggests that the idea is to have public classes exposed from the library which hide their setters.  This solution only succeeds when the implementing type is internal (make it public and the setter is now public also) and therefore of little use to code referencing the library - unless the library uses factories that only produce instances of the public interface.

Comment: @FrederikGheysels you can't use an `internal` setter to implement an interface member - even if the interface is `internal` - implicit interface implementations like this must always be `public`.  For reduced-visibility implementations you only have explicit implementations (e.g. `object IFoo.Bar { get; set; }`)

Comment: @AndrasZoltan: in the scenario where I have used this in the past, the public API interfaces are in one assembly, and the internal API interfaces are in another. Limit who accesses the internal API and you limit access to the setters.

Comment: @AndrasZoltan: I never said you have to make the setter a part of the interface.  That's the whole thing...  public interface IFoo { int Bar {get;}}  and then, you can have a class which looks like this public class Foo : IFoo { public int Bar { get; internal set;} }

Answer (score 1):

You can have the internal interface extend the public interface, like so:

```
public interface MyInternalInterface: MyPublicInterface
{
    string MyProperty { set; }
}

public interface MyPublicInterface
{
    string MyProperty { get; }
}

internal class A: MyInternalInterface
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    private A _a = new A();
    internal MyInternalInterface GetInternalA() { return _a; }
    public MyPublicInterface GetA() { return _a; }

}
```

This way you don't need any casts or anything.

Comment: If `A` is public and its `MyProperty` getter and setter are both public, then you can circumvent the protection of the setter afforded by the internal interface by just writing to the property through the public class.  Equally - if you change the class to internal you've got the same answer as @adrianbanks

Answer (score 0):

*I thought that @adrianbanks' answer might be an improvement on mine, however I don't think it really is (despite being nifty) - because you have no guarantee that a public interface instance being passed to you also implements the internal one - which is also true of this solution.  There's also the thing that it only works if the implementing type is `internal` - which is no good if you want to supply public types as standard interface implementations or as bases for a hierarchy.*

This is what I use.  Given:

```
interface myInterface
{
  string myProperty { get; set; }
}

public interface myPublicInterface
{
  string myProperty { get; }
}
```

First you *can't* make `myPublicInterface` inherit `myInterface` because the compiler will moan about inconsistent accessibility.  So you can explicitly implement the internal one, using a property backer, and then implement the public one implicitly:

```
public class MyClass : myInterface, myPublicInterface
{
    private string _myProperty;

    string myInterface.myProperty
    {
        get { return _myProperty; }
        set { _myProperty = value; }
    }

    public string myProperty
    {
        get { return _myProperty; }
    }
}
```

Note - in some cases, the getter might not be suitable for a private backer, but might be some logic that calculates values from other properties.  In which case - to keep it DRY - you can put the logic in the public getter, and leech that for the explicit getter:

```
string myInterface.myProperty
{
  get { return MyProperty; }
  set { /*whatever logic you need to set the value*/ }
}

public string myProperty
{
  get { /*whatever complex logic is used to get the value*/ }
}
```

You can do it the other way around, but you have to do a horrible-looking inline cast to the internal interface:

```
string myInterface.myProperty
{
  get { /*whatever complex logic is used to get the value*/ }
  set { /*whatever logic you need to set the value*/ }
}

public string myProperty
{
  get { return ((myInterface)this).myProperty; }
}
```

Which you should try to steer clear of wherever possible.